# syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: scripts, minecraft

This is a start.sh for Minecraft server (start and auto restart)

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
java -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -jar Spigot.jar
sleep 5
done
```

And after I start it, the console say:

```
bash: start.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
bash: start.sh: line 6: `done'
```

Update:
I have change #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
java -Xms4096M -Xmx4096M -jar server.jar
sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can try a single line:

```
while true; do java -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -jar Spigot.jar; sleep 5; done
```